# VS2008 Not color coding html code on aspx pages

Tags: visual-studio-2008

VS2008 has suddenly stopped color coding the HTML on all aspx pages. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: A coworker of mine also has this problem from time to time. She fixes it by restarting VS2008. Have you tried restarting VS2008?

Comment: a couple times already. It doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe VS2008 is opening the .aspx file with the wrong editor.  Try right-clicking the file and choose the "Open With..." option.  That should let you choose an editor and set your default option.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to command prompt
and type the below url (or) where your visual studio was installed

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE (its for VS2008)

then type below two commands

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe/setup

c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv/resetskippkgs

then u can get the previous settings and works fine for me